# finding a specific date in MySql

Tags: mysql, date

I knew this will give syntax error.
`SELECT DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 3 MONTH)),INTERVAL EXTRACT(DAY FROM (DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 3 MONTH))) DAY) as oldDate`

I am new to SQL and in here I am trying to find 3 month old date and the first day of that month.
for example 3 month old date from today will be 28-11-2014 so I have to show 01-11-2014.
so how to sort above code to avoid syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DATE_FORMAT to format the date according to your requirements.

```
  SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 3months_ago,
         DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH), "01-%m-%Y") first_day
    FROM DUAL

   +---------------------+------------+
   | 3months_ago         | first_day  |
   +---------------------+------------+
   | 2014-11-28 09:20:50 | 01-11-2014 |
   +---------------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date_format()` function along with `date_sub()` to get the 1st day of month

```
mysql> select date_format(date_sub(curdate(),interval 3 month),'01-%m-%Y') ;
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| date_format(date_sub(curdate(),interval 3 month),'01-%m-%Y') |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| 01-11-2014                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```